# POST JSON with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, post

I use this code,

```
let username = usernameText.text
let pass = passTxt.text
let pass2 = pass2Txt.text

let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.6/ff/jsonsignup.php");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(pass)&c_password=\(pass2)";

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil
    {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

   print("response = \(response)")

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")


           let myJSON = try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = myJSON as NSDictionary! {

        var firstNameValue = parseJSON["username"] as? String
        print("Username: \(firstNameValue)")
    }

}

task.resume()
```

responseString

```
Username: {"username":"Optional(\"ttttt\")"}
```

Optional extra added phrase

BUT

I went, as I want to get sent

```
{"username":"ttttt"}
```

I wonder where the error making ?

Comment: Try this: `print("Username: \(firstNameValue!)")`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the Optional keyword because when you get any data out of a dictionary it will always give you an Optional.

[Optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) means it may contain the object or it may contain nil. Just a safer way of programming

Just Unwrap the optional using if let statement

```
   if let firstNameValue = parseJSON["username"] as? String
   {
      print("Username: \(firstNameValue)")
   }
```

Comment: It's like the following while recording to the database.
I think about what is not told